# Getting different errors while importing Excel file through SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I am importing an Excel file into SQL Server using `SqlBulkCopy`

But every time I get differant errors like

> *Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.*

or

> *Could not find installable ISAM.*

or

> *The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.*

Check my code below...

```
String strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+filepath+";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;";

//Create Connection to Excel work book
OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

//Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand
("Select * from [Sheet1$]",
excelConnection);
MessageBox.Show("ss");
excelConnection.Open();
MessageBox.Show("ss2");
OleDbDataReader dReader;
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
MessageBox.Show("ss1");
SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "RecExcelTable";
//sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
//sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
```

Also I need to compitable this code for any version of Excel.

How can I do that and solve my error?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.  Check that the file path is correct

do like

```
C:\\file.xls
```

as a test.

And also check that the version is correct. 8.0 is pretty old I think thats like office 2000, no ?